# Retrieval of ToolStripButton events throws an exception

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I'm trying to get the list of events of a ToolStripButton and an error is happening on line 6 of my code:

```
public void GetEventHandlerList(ToolStripButton tsb)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = tsb.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
    EventHandlerList eventHandlerList = propertyInfo.GetValue(tsb, new object[] { }) as EventHandlerList;
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(ToolStripButton).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    object eventKey = fieldInfo.GetValue(tsb);
    var eventHandler = eventHandlerList[eventKey] as Delegate;
    Delegate[] invocationList = eventHandler.GetInvocationList(); // <<<<<<==== Erro

 // rest of the code
}
```

Always returning null. I have an overload of this method where the parameter is a "Control" and works properly. What might be going wrong? 
PS: Sorry if the format was not right. I am new here and want to do everything right.

Comment: Hard to guess how you got this far, it should be type(ToolStripItem).GetField(...).  And if (eventHandler == null) then there are no event handlers.  Proper attribution for code you didn't write yourself is required here btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one binding flag in the GetField (line 3): BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy.

Without it, you will not find the field "EventClick" and fieldInfo will always be NULL and this by itself will cause a problem.

I tested your code with this change and it works without errors if you actually have an event associated with the Click event, and causes an exception otherwise (see Hans Passant comment about testing for null).